# Como actualizar los paquetes en proyecto asp.net mvc5 por defecto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Como actualizar los paquetes y librerías que usa visual estudio por defecto en los proyectos de MVC5 sé que si voy a el administrador de nuget packet manager y le doy actualizar todo , lo hace pero solo al proyecto que tengo abierto, lo que estoy buscando es que cada vez que cree un nuevo proyecto ya tenga las librerías actualizadas por lo menos hasta donde yo la actualicé para no estar actualizando con cada proyecto que cree.

Comment: amigo pero tanto te cuesta hacer eso que ya sabes? o es que creas un proyecto nuevo cada 2min?

Comment: Hola, es que mi conexión a internet es inestable y no sé cuando tenga internet, además como soy estudiante siempre estoy creando un nuevo proyecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las plantillas de VS son modificables, estan en la carpeta de instalacion, podrias personalizar la que usas actualmente para que este disponible como un nuevo template(me parece lo mas adecuado) o en lugar de la que esta actualmente, 
[aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx) encontras mas informacion de las plantillas

Comment: Gracias men funcionó!